# gradle android project two java source directories

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have follow project structure:

```
|--RootProject
|  |--Project1
|     
|  |--Project2
```

Project1 and Project2 are Android projects. I try to build Project1 using gradle build script in Idea.
I just try to link more java source folder for my main gradle layout in Project1. I try this:

```
android{
   ..
   main{
     java.srcDir '../Project2/src/main/java'
     ..
   }
}
```

Gradle script doesn't link java sources from Project2 to Project1. Is any idea?